# Cron Expresion Which starts at 11:50 PM and ends at 12:20 PM

Tags: java, cron

I have written a cron expression which starts at `11:50 PM` and ends at `12:20 PM`

CRON Expression :

```
* 50,20 11-12 ? * *
```

Result: Triggers at 11:50 PM and 12:20 PM

Expected Result: Should start at 11:50 PM and end at 12:20 PM

But the above expression is not giving exact result. Can someone help me out with this.

Comment: What you mean by "not giving exact result"? What result you get? What do you expect to get?

Comment: BTW you expression means 11:20, 11:50, 12:20, 12:50. `Cron` doesn't operate with intervals.

Comment: @talex1 No i should get an cron which starts at 11:50 and ends at 12:20

Comment: What do you mean by that? You want it to bi triggered every minute of that interval?

Comment: @talex yes it should triggered every minute starting from 11:50 and ending at 12:20

Comment: `cron` doesn't support that. You need two `cron` expression.

Comment: @talex cant we do it using single cron?

Comment: No. `cron` doesn't support that.